# add data to pre-existing csv file via nodejs and ya-csv

Tags: node.js, csv

I was hoping someone could shed some light on this for me...
I can't for the life of me work out how to append data using **nodejs** and **ya-csv**(module) to a pre-existing csv file. (in this case called staff.csv)
If I were to run this script twice the csv file would be overwritten rather than updated to hold both the old and new information.
Don't suppose anyone out there has a decent grasp of ya-csv and could help me out or knows of an alternative?

```
dictionary = {
//data...
};

var csv = require('ya-csv');
var w = csv.createCsvFileWriter('staff.csv');
var data = [];
for(key in dictionary) {
if(typeof dictionary[key] !== 'function'){
    data.push(key);
    data.push(dicitonary[key]);
}
}
w.writeRecord(data);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to pass correct `options` object to `createCsvFileWriter` function:

```
var w = csv.createCsvFileWriter('staff.csv', {'flags': 'a'});
```

`'a'` here means "append". It allows you to add content to the end of an existing file. For all avaliable flags see [Nodejs Documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_open_path_flags_mode_callback).

Comment: ahhh! thankyou so much, I'm new node and had missed that detail.  Lifesaver! cheers!